# Create a Dockerfile for windows application/Windows Service using .Net framework

Tags: .net, dockerfile, .net-framework-version

I am new to dockerization and trying to write a docker file for a windows application.

I tried generating a dockerfile using Visual studio code. The generated one is for .Net Core, but I need for .Net Framework.

Comment: can you please mark my answer, thanks

Answer (score -1):

Checkout the official repository for .Net Framework
https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet-framework/

```
docker run -itd --name "MyDotnet" -v "/my/local/path:/home/xdev" microsoft/dotnet-framework
```

Then you can deploy your Application in your local mounted directory

**For .Net Core** 
please see my Dockerfile for .Net Core as an example

```html
FROM xzesstence/docker-ubuntu
MAINTAINER "Tim Koepsel"

LABEL dotnet-version="2.1.4"

ENV TZ 'Europe/Brussels'

# https://bugs.debian.org/830696 (apt uses gpgv by default in newer releases, rather than gpg)
RUN set -ex; \
        apt-get update; \
        if ! which gpg; then \
                apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gnupg; \
        fi; \
# Ubuntu includes "gnupg" (not "gnupg2", but still 2.x), but not dirmngr, and gnupg 2.x requires dirmngr
# so, if we're not running gnupg 1.x, explicitly install dirmngr too
        if ! gpg --version | grep -q '^gpg (GnuPG) 1\.'; then \
                 apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends dirmngr; \
        fi; \
        rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


RUN apt-key adv --keyserver packages.microsoft.com --recv-keys EB3E94ADBE1229CF && apt-key adv --keyserver packages.microsoft.com --recv-keys 52E16F86FEE04B979B07E28DB02C46DF417A0893

RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update \
 && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone \
 && apt-get install -y net-tools \
                       iputils-ping \
                       curl \
                       wget \
                       ca-certificates \
                       unzip \
                       tzdata \
 && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | /usr/bin/gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg \
 && mv microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg \
 && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-bionic-prod bionic main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list' \
 && apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-2.1.105  \
                       aspnetcore-store-2.0.6

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime \
 && dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata \
 && apt-get clean \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


RUN useradd -d /home/xdev -ms /bin/bash -g root -G sudo xdev
RUN echo 'xdev:123456' | chpasswd
USER xdev
WORKDIR /home/xdev

ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
CMD ["bash"]
```

You can now build the dockerfile by running

```
docker build --tag dotnet .
```

Then you can run the container and mount a local directory with something like this

```
docker run -itd --name "MyDotnet" -v "/my/local/path:/home/xdev" dotnet
```

You can deploy your net application in /my/local/path on your host machine or change the workdir to the path your want to use

To get into the container

```
docker exec -it MyDotnet bash
```

inside it you can simply type

```
dotnet MyApplication.dll [application arguments]
```

or you need to set the right entrypoint so your dll get started automatically

Please answer as right answer if it works for you

Comment: I need sample Dockerfile for .Net Framework application, but the sample you provided using  

FROM xzesstence/docker-ubuntu.

Could you please provide a correct file.

Comment: Well im using my own Ubuntu Container for all Ubuntu derivates..

Of course you can just use

FROM ubuntu:latest


Please don't forget to mark the answer ;)

Comment: @xzesstence The original question is asking about having .NET Framework on dockerfile. Therefore your answer is irrelevant because your answer describe dockerfile for Linux container, but .NET Framework only runs on Windows. Please update your answer.

Comment: i changed my answer